# React doesn't fully mount a node in case of dynamic generation

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, rendering

I'm working with React (16+) and I have some kind of "component registry" which is a simple object where keys are names of components and values - components.

These components are the realization of FormField. eg they are  Form fields with different type of meaning. Text/ Password etc.

In short: I have some step number and for every step number which have name (email, password etc. I'm rendering a dedicated field) and it works fine but The problem is: **React doesn't fully re-render the whole Field component for the new step**. So if I typo some value for the email and move to the next step - React won't update the field (but it should!) and the field will be from previous step.
I'm just very confused.

Here is my registry:

```
_getStepField() {


 const {
        email,
        first_name,
        last_name,
        gender,
        birthday,
        activeStepNumber
    } = this.state;

    const {
        locale: { formatMessage }
    }: IProps = this.props;

    // TODO: move this stuff outside

    const fieldRegistry = {
        [StepNames.Email]: (
            <FormModule.Field
                name="email"
                inputLabelClassName="sign-up-field-label"
                autoComplete="e-mail"
                value={email}
                margin="normal"
                id="email"
                onChange={this.generateFieldOnChange("email")}
                label={formatMessage("emailFieldLabel")}
                component={renderTextInput}
                validate={[requiredValidatorCreator("E-mail"), emailValidator]}
                onEventAsyncValidate={{
                    onManualTrigger: this.checkIfEmailUsed
                }}
                type="text"
            />
        ),
        [StepNames.Password]: (
                <FormModule.Field
                    name="password"
                    inputLabelClassName="sign-up-field-label"
                    id="password"
                    onChange={this.generateFieldOnChange("password")}
                    autoComplete="your password"
                    label={formatMessage("password")}
                    adornmentAriaLabel={"toggle visibility"}
                    component={renderPassInput}
                    validate={[requiredValidatorCreator("Password")]}
                    type="password"
                />
        ),
        [StepNames.FirstName]: (
                <FormModule.Field
                    name="first_name"
                    inputLabelClassName="sign-up-field-label"
                    autoComplete="first-name"
                    value={first_name}
                    margin="normal"
                    id="first_name"
                    onChange={this.generateFieldOnChange("first_name")}
                    label={formatMessage("firstName")}
                    component={renderTextInput}
                    type="text"
                />
        ),
        [StepNames.LastName]: (
                <FormModule.Field
                    name="last_name"
                    inputLabelClassName="sign-up-field-label"
                    autoComplete="last-name"
                    value={last_name}
                    margin="normal"
                    id="last_name"
                    onChange={this.generateFieldOnChange("last_name")}
                    label={formatMessage("lastName")}
                    component={renderTextInput}
                    type="text"
                />
        ),

    };

    const stepName: string = this.stepOrderNamesList[activeStepNumber];
    return fieldRegistry[stepName];
}
```

I've found a very ugly solution to fight this issue. If I wrap each field into some unique tag it will be rendered correctly. But it's a lil bit strange solution so if anyone can help me with this or give some tip I'll be very appreciate!  Thanks for any help!

Here is my current bad solution:

```
_getStepField() {


 const {
        email,
        first_name,
        last_name,
        gender,
        birthday,
        activeStepNumber
    } = this.state;

    const {
        locale: { formatMessage }
    }: IProps = this.props;

    // TODO: move this stuff outside

    const fieldRegistry = {
        [StepNames.Email]: (
          <div> /* --> The tag different than the prev one */
            <FormModule.Field
                name="email"
                inputLabelClassName="sign-up-field-label"
                autoComplete="e-mail"
                value={email}
                margin="normal"
                id="email"
                onChange={this.generateFieldOnChange("email")}
                label={formatMessage("emailFieldLabel")}
                component={renderTextInput}
                validate={[requiredValidatorCreator("E-mail"), emailValidator]}
                onEventAsyncValidate={{
                    onManualTrigger: this.checkIfEmailUsed
                }}
                type="text"
            />
         </div>
        ),
        [StepNames.Password]: (
            <section> /* --> The tag different than the prev one */
                <FormModule.Field
                    name="password"
                    inputLabelClassName="sign-up-field-label"
                    id="password"
                    onChange={this.generateFieldOnChange("password")}
                    autoComplete="your password"
                    label={formatMessage("password")}
                    adornmentAriaLabel={"toggle visibility"}
                    component={renderPassInput}
                    validate={[requiredValidatorCreator("Password")]}
                    type="password"
                />
          </section>
        ),
        [StepNames.FirstName]: (
              <p> /* --> The tag different than the prev one */
                <FormModule.Field
                    name="first_name"
                    inputLabelClassName="sign-up-field-label"
                    autoComplete="first-name"
                    value={first_name}
                    margin="normal"
                    id="first_name"
                    onChange={this.generateFieldOnChange("first_name")}
                    label={formatMessage("firstName")}
                    component={renderTextInput}
                    type="text"
                />
           </p>
        ),
        [StepNames.LastName]: (
            <div> /* --> The tag different than the prev one */
                <FormModule.Field
                    name="last_name"
                    inputLabelClassName="sign-up-field-label"
                    autoComplete="last-name"
                    value={last_name}
                    margin="normal"
                    id="last_name"
                    onChange={this.generateFieldOnChange("last_name")}
                    label={formatMessage("lastName")}
                    component={renderTextInput}
                    type="text"
                />
            </div> 
        ),

    };

    const stepName: string = this.stepOrderNamesList[activeStepNumber];
    return fieldRegistry[stepName];
}
```

Comment: probably adding `key` for wrapper element would do the trick.

Comment: bro, you are right! Thank you.  How I didn't figured it out before